# Is Rubocop Method Name Length Configurable?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I know a number of the other Metrics are configurable in the `.rubocop.yaml` file, but I haven't found anything for this. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [this is explained in the documentation](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/master/config/default.yml).

Comment: Does there actually exist a check for method name length or is it just line length? I just tested with a super long method name and only got the "Line is too long" warning.

Comment: There's a flag you can pass when you run rubocop to show you what the cop name is. Posting the cop name should help improve this question

Comment: tadman: I haven't seen anything in the documentation regarding a specific cop for line length. Can you link to the line in the documentation that covers this specific configuration item? I'm more inclined to agree with Andy's answer that one doesn't exist yet (though something is causing RubyMine to flag it).

JayDorsey: I'll play around with flag a bit to see what it brings back, thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing cop for method **name** length, but it would be possible to write one:

https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/master/manual/development.md